# IOS application stops updating location on server after some time

Tags: ios, background-service

We are developing an iOS application which continuously updates user's current location on the server.

We are facing an issue where the updates seem to stop coming to our server after continuous running for 30mins or so.

We think the background code that checks for user's location and sends updates to our server is being freezed by the OS after some time.

Any suggestions to overcome this problem are welcome.

Comment: can you add your code here?

Comment: Can you show some code?  How do you start location updates?  Do you start from the foreground or the background? Do you allow location updates to pause?

Answer (score 0):

I will presume you mean when the app is backgrounded. An app will by default only be given a limited amount of processing time after an app has been backgrounded. This is 3 minutes in iOS9 as far as I can remember.

There are exceptions to this rule which include location services - so you may be in luck. To do this you will need to add the 'UIBackgroundModes' key to you plist to define what you intend to do with this extended background time.

More details here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html